# Scrolling long wrapped lines in Vim

Tags: vim

**Problem**: When writing prose scrolling works in unexpected way when using `j` to scroll down. As I scroll between two long paragraphs (wrapped lines in vim) of text using `j`, when reaching the next long paragraph (line) the text "jumps" from the bottom of the screen to the top, aligning the first word of the paragraph (line) with the top of the screen (see screenshots bellow).

**Affected**: Folks who love Vim and want to use it to write prose.

**Expected**: I would like the paragraph (line) to jump to the middle of the screen OR to continue scrolling with the cursor at the bottom. The jump is too jarring otherwise--I am losing context. Two questions: **1)** Is it possible to change the default behavior in .vimrc? **2)** If not, how feasible would it be to write a plug-in altering the behavior?

**Related Resources**:

- http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Long-lines-and-scrolling-td1183898.html
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_through_wrapped_lines
- http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Scrolling-Long-Lines-Revisited-Again-td5031203.html

For example: here I am scrolling down some dummy text: [image: frame1].

After `jj` the next paragraph has moved up to the top of the screen: [image: frame2]

My .vimrc is [here](https://github.com/denten/.dotfiles/blob/master/). Prose mode is:

```
command! Prose setlocal linebreak nolist wrap wrapmargin=0
nnoremap k gk
nnoremap j gj
```

Comment: Those aren't really paragraphs. They are very very long wrapped lines.

Comment: @FDinoff How else would you input a paragraph?

Comment: @Jivan a paragraph is a block of text separated by blank lines. It just so happens that the line in the picture is 941 characters long with a blank line in front of it and a blank line after it. So while yes it is a paragraph. It is a really bad paragraph.

Comment: @OllieFord with a lot line breaks. You can force vim to insert them with `set textwidth=80` and `gq<motion>`

Answer (score 3):

Vim is essentially a line-based editor. You're using `:set wrap` to display the entirety of long lines. Still, Vim still tries to keep the *beginning* of the current long line visible (for features like `:set number`), which showing as much of the entire line. With excessively long lines (that take up most of the windows, as in your screenshots), that results in the current line scrolling to the top of the window. I'm afraid there's nothing to prevent that. You can only workaround, either by increasing the size of the Vim window, or by editing with hard line breaks in the text.

Comment: Editing with line breaks would be easy with formatting options and there's ways to tell Vim that a `.<Space>` at the end of a line is /not/ the end a paragraph

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's the logic for it, @IngoKarkat. The beginning of the line would be visible at the bottom of the screen just fine. I think Vim is trying to show as much of the line as possible. Seems like there should be a setting to disable that behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; sorry if I wasn't clear. An option would certainly be nice, but I'm only aware of the slightly related `:set display=lastline`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is one of Vim's problems. The command `gq` exists which can help you to format the text based on the text width you've set, which can save some time. `se formatoptions+=a` is helpful, as it will reformat the text as you edit it, so you don't have to keep hitting gq. The problem is, of course, now you have to define your paragraphs by blank lines, and it's not a very well rounded solution if you needed to scroll by screen lines for some other reason (such as a very long json object on one line, or log files or whatever).

Briefly looking at it, when using the gnu GUI version of emacs, it seems I can actually scroll with the mouse wheel by screen lines. This is unlike MacVim. So it looks like emacs at least has some kind of support for it. If you're writing prose, you may be able to get by just with the EVIL mode plugin for emacs, which is not complete but is a pretty sophisticated version of vim inside emacs. In general, emacs is a little more pliable for people who really like to tinker and touch every part of the system to do new things, so someone has probably written some good prose modes for it. Obviously it doesn't let you leverage your existing vimscripts, though.

From following your links, it looks like this scroll by screen lines issue has been on Bram's radar for 20 years. My guess is there's something tricky about implementing it in the existing system. It's too bad, because not only do people often get confused by what is wanted when someone asks this question, but there are plenty of simple reasons you would want it, too. It comes up rarely in code, and constantly in every other type of document.

Answer (score 1):

It will help to brief yourself on VIM's motion commands `{` and `}` are good ones with literary text. However in the case you describe these are not paragraphs they are lines. VIM manages them as lines. As such you had to go so far as to remap `j` and `k` which is the reverse of usual. My suggestion is to break the lines into paragraphs by way of `textwidth`.

Finally VIM has screen commands to manipulate the viewable area. Since VIM is attempting to show you as much context as possible (in your case a extremely long line) it takes up the whole screen and you see the "jump" To reverse this use the `zz` (AKA `z<Enter>`) command to move the screen viewable area to match the cursor in the center. The others are `zt` to place the viewable area to the top and `zb` to place the viable area to the bottom.

Hope these suggestions help and happy VIMing.

Comment: Thanks! I am still looking to change the behavior. Would there be anyway to change the line from jumping up screen?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @denten they are not paragraphs they are long lines.

When you navigate using `j` or `k`; you are moving vertically through the same column. But with your mapping (`j` to `gj` and `k` to `gk`) you are moving vertically as visually wrapped by the editor.

I suggest to remove that mapping and use `gj` & `gk` manually as required.

Additionally if *scrolling* is your requirement, consider mapping `PageUp` & `PageDown` with the following:

```
" Slow PageUp/PageDown
nnoremap <silent> <PageUp> <c-y>
nnoremap <silent> <PageDown> <c-e>
```

Or if the idea of using `PageUp` or `PageDown` feel awkward, feel free to go with the actual keys to scroll: `Control` and `y` for up; and `Control` and `e` for down.

Comment: I use `<C-d>` / `<C-u>` and `<C-f>` / `<C-b>` for keyboard based scrolling.

Comment: Okay, then ignore the scrolling part. Just wrote as you mentioned scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Jukku! I would still like to change the behavior of the line that is far down the screen moving up to the top of the screen when using j.

Comment: Does anyone know how to delete a visual line?