# Move current display line at top of window in vim (j : zt = gj : ???)

Tags: vim

`zt` or `z<CR>` in normal mode redraws the buffer, cursor line at top of window.
This is handy, but it is worthless when reading a file with *very* long lines.

I have `set wrap`, so sometimes one line fills up the entire display, when I want `zt`-like functionalities.

Is there a correspondent, "redraw the buffer, current *display line* at top of window"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's support of editing wrapped lines is limited; there is little support beyond the by-screen-line navigation of `gj` / `gk`. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751462/scrolling-long-wrapped-lines-in-vim) has been asked recently. In particular, commands like `zt` or `<C-E>` / `<C-Y>` are based on *physical* lines. It certainly would be great to have corresponding commands that work on screen lines, too. I'll invite you to write a patch for that (note that this isn't trivial and requires some knowledge about Vim's implementation).

Without that, you can only try to emulate this. I think the only way to scroll by screen line is via moving the cursor to the bottom of the window and then doing `gj`.